# Rendering SVG icons in GTK4 apps on Windows

Tags: windows, svg, gtk, gtk4, gtk-rs

I wonder what is necessary to render theme aware icons in gtk-rs (GTK4) on Windows. I added icons to resources and can successfully render PNG files. Drop-in replacement with SVG does not render anything.
Would it be possible to use icon-fonts like in web development? If so, how can I add a custom font in gtk4?

my folder structure

```
[root]
  resources/
    icons/
      scalable/
        actions/
          svgicon.svg
          pngicon.png
    gresources.xml
  src/
    main.rs
    window.ui
    window.rs
  build.rs
  Cargo.toml
```

gresources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/myapp/gui/">
    <file compressed="true">icons/scalable/actions/pngicon.png</file>
    <file compressed="true">icons/scalable/actions/svgicon.svg</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

window.ui

```
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPicture">
            <property name="file">resource:///myapp/gui/icons/scalable/actions/svgicon.svg</property>
            <property name="width-request">100</property>
            <property name="height-request">100</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPicture">
            <property name="file">resource:///myapp/gui/icons/scalable/actions/pngicon.png</property>
            <property name="width-request">100</property>
            <property name="height-request">100</property>
          </object>
        </child>
```

As mentioned the png image renders but svg doesn't. I read people could use librsvg to render the svgs on windows but this can't compile because of missing libxml2 on windows. I wonder why this is so problematic and how the freedesktop (default icons) are built and rendered in gtk?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I could answer my answer on my own now. At the end of the rustbook for gtk-rs it explains how to use libadwita (which I am not interested in) and there it explains librsvg can be built as well with gvsbuild tool similar like gtk4 has been build `gvsbuild build libadwaita librsvg`

Building this library instantly fixed my issue of not loading svgs.